# htaccess rewrite posts sub directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, blogs

I'm in the process of moving a Wordpress blog from the root ...com to ...com/blog/

Currently all the posts from 2010 - 2012 start this way .com/2010 - .com/2011 - .com/2012

I'd like to catch only urls that have 2010, 2011 and 2012 following .com and add blog in front.

> Example:
>
> *www.domain.com/2012/1/post-title/*
>
> needs to become
>
> *www.domain.com/**blog**/2012/1/post-title/*

I still have wordpress pages in the root and want to make sure they don't redirect too.

Here is the default wordpress htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
RewriteRule ^2012/(.*) /blog/2012/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The new .htaccess file would be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^2010/(.*) /blog/2010/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2011/(.*) /blog/2011/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2012/(.*) /blog/2012/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I hope above rules are self explanatory.
You can optimize above rule in 3 lines can to 1 line.